# CiviXero invoice push error

Tags: gocardless, civixero

CiviXero has not "pushed" transactions to Xero. The effect of this is that there are huge discrepancies when attempting to reconcile bank account data.

As an example I have a contribution ID that is 34220 showing as complete in CiviCRM, handled by Go Cardless.

In the Civicrm_accounts_invoice table there's an entry for the contrib but there is no accounts fields data other than Account Needs update = 1.

Over at Xero, there is no entry for the contribution ID so it cannot find any match for reconciliating bank accounts.

It's just not synching the contributions. Seems limited to Go Cardless contributions.

I would really appreciate any advise as to how to make these contributions get passed to Xero.

Comment: what are the Scheduled Jobs reporting?

Comment: It was reporting an account sync  extension error. Anyway I disabled and re-enabled Go Cardless and Accountsync with latest versions from GitHub and everything is working fine.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I'm now cross checking with Xero invoices receivable and Im not really seeing anything new turning up. The log is showing Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:2:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:6:"plugin";s:4:"xero";}

Full message: 
Finished execution of CiviXero Invoice Push Job with result: Success (25)